# What is the back story or history behind Facebook's 'Putnam' smiley?

Tags: facebook

Please explain the reason for and back story to Facebook's hidden ***PUTNAM*** smiley (`:putnam:`).

Here it is: [image: :putnam:]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Chris Putnam is a software engineer at Facebook. [Here](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?blog_id=company&blogger=13) is his blog and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgpEWmlxLhQ) is an interview with the guy.

I don't know why he merited an easter-egg emoticon over other potential candidates. I'm not sure there has to be a reason.

[In 2006, Chris Putnam hacked Facebook](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kb3nZDtRH_g), changing thousands of profiles to a MySpace style. He was then hired by Facebook.

Answer (score 6):

As stated already, Chris Putnam works for Facebook and no doubt put the `:putnam:` smiley in there as a little [Easter Egg.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29#Computer-related_Easter_eggs)

I think the idea for the `:putnam:` smiley is to use it when mentioning an iconic figure or an extremely intelligent / successful person.

This probably stems from how Chris Putnam got the job at Facebook.  He hacked in to Facebook profile page and created a viral worm that spread to most users.  He then changed the CSS so that all profile pages looked like MySpace.